# Index template shows a policy that doesn’t exist

Tags: elasticsearch

Index Template is showing a policy lifecycle that doesn't exist.
any idea how come this happens?

```
GET /index-name/_ilm/explain?pretty
{
  "indices" : {
    ".ds-index-name-2022.01.12-000001" : {
      "index" : ".ds-index-name-2022.01.12-000001",
      "managed" : true,
      "policy" : "index-policies",
      "step_info" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "policy [index-policies] does not exist"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The policy existed when the index was created, but it must have been deleted in the meantime. Whenever a policy is removed, the indexes managed by that policy stop being managed.

Or, the index could have been restored from an old snapshot taken prior to the policy deletion.

This case should be taken care of [by this fix](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/40820), though.